# Form getting submitted despite of returning false in onsubmit()

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on html forms
my html code is

```
<form onsubmit="check_credentials()" action="index.php/welcome/add" method="post">
      <div  class="sign_up_entry"> <span>Email Address:</span> <input type="text" id="signup_email" name="email" class="form-control" onfocusout="check_credentials_email()"/></div>
      <div  class="sign_up_entry"> <span>Username:</span> <input type="text" id="signup_username" name="username" class="form-control" onfocusout="check_credentials_username()"/></div>
      <div  class="sign_up_entry"> <span>Password:</span> <input type="password" id="signup_password" name="password" class="form-control"/></div>
      <button value="Sign Up" type="submit" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

and javascript is

```
function check_credentials()
{
   return false;
}
```

but my form always get submitted, whats the problem?

Comment: thought so, wasnt sure.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return false from the event handler function, but you aren't returning anything.

Your event handler function is calling `check_credentials`, doing nothing with the return value of that, and then returning nothing itself.

```
onsubmit="return check_credentials()"
```

---

In general, it is considered better to avoid using intrinsic event handler attributes at all and [unobtrusively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) bind your event handlers.

e.g.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', check_credentials);

function check_credentials(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```